# Alien painter on a desert planet. 60's short story

Tags: story-identification

This is a 60's SF short story maybe from Astounding or Analog.
A space ship crashes on a desert planet with maybe a large bluish star (S Doradus ?)
it involves some thing painting the scene which maybe turns out to be painted by an alien??

Any help with tracking this down is much appreciated.

Comment: There's a Russian short story about a space mission that sees the captain staying behind on the planet of another star ( Barnard's IIRC) in order to allow the rest of the crew to return to Earth. And he's a painter, and when the rescue mission arrives, they find him dead, but having painted miraculously beautiful paintings. As ANALOG have done foreign writer editions, and the time is right, maybe this is it?

Comment: not this story but thanks for posting

Answer (score 3):

Could it have been in *New Worlds*?

[Issue #60 (June 1957)](https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_060v20_1957-06) contains John Brunner's [*Eye of the Beholder*]
(https://archive.org/stream/New_Worlds_060v20_1957-06#page/n71/mode/2up).

> The humans are admiring the paintings when the painter turns up. But he's an alien monster and they promptly shoot him, assuming that he must have murdered the human artist. The planet in question circled a B-type star.

Answer (score -1):

The story you're looking for is ["The Astronaut"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?961581) by Valentina Zhuravlyova

Comment: Can you provide some details to back up your assertion?

Comment: Adventure stories for girls and boys PGE 243. A captain stays behind to save the crew when a rescue mission  go's back to the star they find his paintings which are taken back. The story starts off in the central astronautics archives.  ISBN 0861782852. Octopus books 1984

Comment: That would appear to be the same story referenced in the comment by @Covertwalrus, which the OP said was not the answer.